# 2007 Honda Civic Will Not Start Unless Steering Wheel Is Turned To The Left

Tags: honda, civic, starter

MY 2007 Honda Civic won't start unless I pull very hard on the steering wheel to the left. It will try to turn over but nothing happens until the wheel is turned.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have something wrong with the starter kill anti-theft functions that reside within the steering wheel lock mechanism.  I would suggest taking it to the dealer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of that could affect the engine itself in this way is the power steering pump. Meaning the starter couldn't turn the engine because the belt can't turn the power steering pump. Check the pump fluid level and the fluid itself. If the steering is not very heavy and the pump doesn't make noise it could be some sort of a hydraulic lock, though that would be quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how hard "very hard" means, but there is a system to prevent turning the steering wheel when the key is not inserted. If you have accidentally turned the steering wheel when the key is not inserted, the lock may engage, and it may then be possible that you cannot freely turn the key without either turning the steering wheel to the left or to the right at the same time as trying to turn the key. However, not much force is required for this.

However, the poster wasn't very specific on what "nothing happens" means. Does it mean that the key can be freely turned but the car doesn't start? Or does it mean that they key cannot be freely turned?

If it means that they key cannot be freely turned, I would assume there is something wrong in this lock mechanism to prevent turning the steering wheel without the key.